# Any advantage to using CountDownTimer() over working directly with System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a few timers I need to run simultaneously. I know that there is an issue with CountDownTimer when it gets down towards the finalization phase [onFinish()] where sometimes it will finish a little early, but don't know much else about the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other. Calling System.currentTimeMillis() directly has to be lighter, but CountDownTimer has to have some sort of advantage other than just ease of use, no?

For example, something just like

```
long totalTime = 30000;
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(totalTime > startTime - currTime){
    currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
System.out.println("Finished!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage of `CountDownTimer` is the regular notifications that you receive during the countdown. Those notifications provide an easy way to *reactively* respond to the time remaining as opposed to *proactively* calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which would probably require some sort of timer mechanism anyway. `CountDownTimer` does the timer setup, callbacks, and cleanup on your behalf.

Your example code will keep the CPU very busy (thus consuming more battery life) with no benefit. It will also make the app's UI non-responsive if the code is running on the main thread. The `CountDownTimer`, on the other hand, won't stall the UI and will only consume CPU time when it's doing notifications. From a performance and ease-of-use perspective, using `CountDownTimer` is the right choice.

Comment: I can understand that as an advantage if there is something you need to do throughout the timer process. All I need to do is do something when it is finished. In this case, would CountDownTimer have any real advantage over just doing something like the quick example I edited into my original post?

Comment: Updated my answer. If you're trying to solve the problem "do X after Y time units have passed" and don't care about what happens in the meantime, then it may be preferable to use a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Comment: Great answer. Do you happen to have an idea how CountDownTimer and TimerTask maintain and check system time? I was assuming that they were both making their own System calls which is why I thought doing your own currentTimeMillis call would be lighter.

Comment: The code for `CountDownTimer` is quite simple and is available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java). Internally, it posts messages to a `Handler` that calls `onTick()` at specified intervals in the future. When calculating those intervals, it calls `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.